# How to assign serviceAccount using gcloud compute nodejs client?

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a new virtual machine using gcloud compute nodejs client:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();

async function createVM() {
  try {
    const zone = await compute.zone('us-central1-a');
    const config = {
      os: 'ubuntu',
      http: true,
      https: true,
      metadata: {
        items: [
          {
            key: 'startup-script-url',
            value: 'gs://<path_to_startup_script>/startup_script.sh'
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    const data = await zone.createVM('vm-9', config);
    const operation = data[1];
    await operation.promise();
    return console.log(' VM Created');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}
```

I have a serviceAccount with the needed roles for this VM to call other resources but I can't figure how to where to assign the serviceAccount when creating the new VM. Any pointers are greatly appreciated, I haven't been able to find any documentation and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the service account to use in the new VM by adding a `serviceAccounts` field within the options for config passed into `createVM`.  Here is an example snippet:

```
zone.createVM('name', {
  serviceAccounts: [
    {
      email: '...',
      scopes: [
        '...'
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Reference:

- [Service Account and Access Scopes](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-compute/issues/111) or [Method: instances.insert](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert)
- [createVM](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/Zone.html#createVM) - The `config` object can take all the parameters of the [instance resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/v1/instances).